# Vaadin themes files line separator

Tags: java, maven, vaadin

I am using Windows 10 and the code style check of company accepts only Unix ("LF", "\n") line ending. I added -Dline.separator=$'\n' for maven build but still some files are generated with windows line separator. How "addons.scss" is generated so I can set the line separator when the project is built?

Comment: Ignore the generated files?